# sensitivity analysis without model

Tags: uncertainty, sensitivity-analysis

Perhaps I should call it input-output correlation test, and the tricky part is no model exists between those inputs and outputs. The basic idea is there are many inputs and one output, and I would like to see if there are any methods 1) identify which inputs are strongly linked to outputs or even 2) to decompose uncertainty from output into inputs.

Comment: As stated, this question is probably too vague to be answerable.  Could you clarify what you mean by "input," "output," "strongly linked," and "decompose uncertainty"?  Perhaps offering a small dataset as an example would help you explain.

Comment: @whuber, sorry for the vague info. For instance, some of the output metics is a function of a few binary events like if a user spent x mins or above OR a user has clicked x number of things for example. My question is what is the best approach of finding correlation between output metric and its possible inputs (then I can find the one or few with strongest associations.).  In terms of inputs, they can be anything as long as measurable, like how many mins a user opened this page, how many people followed, how many blocked, etc.

Comment: This is often done as part of the model building process and a wide array of methods exist. The process is iterated between building models then testing their performance, and can include sensitivity of the output to the inputs (often for variable selection). To control overfit risk the data is typically split into training, validation and test sets. It is also not uncommon for people to pre-filter their variables using an appropriate statistical test to identify the variables least likely to be informative. It sounds like you mean the latter.

Comment: @ReneBt, I think my motivation is to identify strong correlations (linear and non-linear) between inputs and outputs without building a model because when you build a model, people will argue about the decision of including or not-including certain parameters. But given the feedback so far, it seems like you have to build a model then start looking into sensitivity etc.